# Email IP Rotation

Tags: php, email, rotation, ip, bulk-email

Is this possible to send emails from same address, but from different IPs? I have heard about IP rotation. Is it possible to rotate Ip using Php?

May be it is a stupid question. But, I am asking this because I am totally ignorant about IP rotation, and I could not find a proper tutorial/article on it that could help me. So, it would be very helpful if you can give me some idea.

Comment: Only possible using multiple mailservers. It's not PHP that sets the sender IP adress but the mailserver the email is sent from.

Comment: @RMK How people use IP rotation? I have seen newsletters from same email address, but different IP addresses.

Comment: Using multiple mailservers. What you could do is use a email delivery service like Amazone SES (http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or Madrill (http://mandrill.com)

Answer (score 0):

## What is IP Address Rotation?

IP Rotation is the process of distributing allocated IPs to a resource randomly or in a configurable manner specified by the administrator.

for example, When a DSL user connects to his ISP, he is assigned an IP address from a pool of available IPs in his ISP's network topology. His internet address becomes whichever IP was allocated to him. If a disconnection occurs, the ISP will allocate next available IP from the available IP pool implementing IP address rotation transparently to the user.

Internet facing daemons on many hosts already implement automatic IP address rotation for incoming traffic. For example, a DNS server might change the IP address of a web server in a round-robin fashion to facilitate load-balancing of incoming traffic or equal distribution of resources among role-based access control lists. This method is commonly employed by large datacenters and organizations.

Real use of IP rotation can be observed for outgoing internet traffic. Since source IP is the foundation of access controls by destination firewalls in all forms of internet communications; by rotating IP addresses, a server, host or service can evade all restrictions put in place.

## IP Address Rotation Methods

There are 4 main strategies in IP Rotation implementations.

- **Pre-configured IPs**: IP rotation takes place at 1 minute intervals. Every minute, your IP address will change to a different one. Setup is automatic, client has no control.
- **Random IPs:** Each connection initiated by the client is assigned a randomly rotating IP. Setup is automatic, client has no control.
- **Burst IPs:** IP addresses are rotated per specified number of hits, usually 10. If you initiated 10 connections, your 11th will be from a different IP. This is perfect option for bursts of hits at short intervals. Say you want to dispatch 10,000 hits in a second, this option would take care of it where they all would go out from the same IP in pre-configured IP option. Setup is automatic, client has no control.
- **Specific IPs:** Client can choose which IP address he wants to use for the outgoing connection by specifying it in his software. For example, connection to x5.net:5/10.10.10.10 will send out your connection from IP address 10.10.10.10

## IP Address Rotation illegitimate uses

Perhaps the most widespread abuse of IP address rotation is from spammers. Almost all spam farms employ some method of IP rotation to fool destination mail servers into believing that email connections are coming from different net blocks. The aim is to be able to deliver as many emails as possible so that their return rate on targeted product is high.

Spammers also deploy rotating IPs in their link exchange farms for rouge SEO firms called BlackHat SEOs. The target is to deceive major Search Engines for better pageranks.

There are various DDOS scenarios possible for when IPs are rotated. However, perpetrators of these attacks mostly prefer botnets.

## IP Address Rotation legitimate uses

- Anti-counterfeiting and anti-piracy agencies deploy IP rotation
  methods for data harvesting or for researching questionable content
- Business intelligence companies use IP rotation to harvest,
  retrieval, scrape or mine data for performance metrics and data
  analytics.
- Quantative and qualitative research companies deploy IP rotation to
  observe variations.
- Data triangulation companies use IP rotation to verify the validity
  of their content.
- Data warehouses use IP rotation to access a wider selection from
  their destinations.
- Corporate firms use IP rotation to eliminate price gouging and
  geotargeted presentation.
- SEO companies use IP rotation to check keyword rankings from
  different localities.

Comment: Nice long copy and paste answer which totally ignores the OP's question about doing this with PHP

Comment: @Anigel two things 1 it is not the copy paste and second if you read the answer you will find the answer about query also

Comment: I did read the answer and I have reread it and find nothing saying explicitly about using it with php

Comment: http://x5.net/faqs/iprotation/technical.html

Comment: @Vineet1982 could you perhaps help me out with this? http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21097/setting-up-an-ip-rotation-service-at-home

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is NO.

PHP does not have any control over what IP address is used to send email. That is controlled by the mail server.

All you could do is get php to rotate round different mail servers to use to send out the email, by specifying the server using a class such as phpmailer, or use a service like AMAZON SES which can do this for you.

Comment: Please consider the following information I got from three email headers sent to me from same email address:

IP: 209.85.217.194
Authentication Results : mta1145.mail.ne1.yahoo.com
Email : BAY168-W132ACB1731FAC77EF82DA50B26B0@phx.gbl

IP: 209.85.217.193
Authentication Results : mta1090.mail.bf1.yahoo.com
Email : 20130726210242.290150@gmx.com


IP: 209.85.217.195
Authentication Results : mta1286.mail.bf1.yahoo.com
Email : 20130726103413.41180@gmx.com


How is this possible that the sending ip is same, though sent from different IP (209.85.217.xxx)?

Comment: Do you really think yahoo only have one single mail server on their network?